# Convergence of sequence of sets is empty set iff limit of symmetric difference of sets exists.

Tags: measure-theory, convergence-divergence

I'am trying to solve one of the exercises of Halmos's measure theory book, but I can't figure it out. Exercises goes as follows:
Let $(E_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ sequence of sets. Define the sequence $(D_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ as follows:
$$D_1=E_1,D_2=D_1\triangle E_2,~~~D_n=D_{n-1}\triangle E_n,~~\forall n\in\mathbb{N}_{\geq 3}.$$ Prove that the sequence $(D_n)$ converge to some set, say $A$, if and only if $\lim_{n}E_n=\emptyset$.

I try to solve it with definitions of limes superior and limes inferior for sequences of sets but I'm struggling with understand what is the role of symmetric difference in limits of sequences of sets. My attempt:
For sufficiency part, let $\lim_{n}D_n=A$ this implies that $\limsup_nD_n-\liminf_nD_n=\emptyset$. So? What is this means? I also try to derive a contradiction with assuming that $\lim_nE_n\neq\emptyset$ but the sequence $(E_n)$ converge to some set, say U. How can I proceed from here? Can I derive a contradiction or is there any proof directly?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match many users' quality standards, so it may attract downvotes, or closed. To prevent that, please edit the question. This will help you recognise and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Comment: Thank you so much, I am new in MSE. I will try to resolve the issues you mentioned. I will include my thoughts on the problem.

Comment: I think you missed that $E_n$ is a monotone sequence.

Comment: No. In exercises there is no additional info about $E_n$.

Comment: What about using the indicator functions?